# Create a chart of a specific columns in a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, excel-2010, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have data in excel and i need show in a pivot table some data with filters of the user,

The problem is that i need show 5 columns:

```
month     Users      revenue      messages    Arpu
```

And i add in my pivot table the 5 columns in my Axis fields i have month, and in my Values i have the sum of the (users, revenue, messages, Arpu), i need show all columns because are very informative. But the problem is that now i need do a chart in columns, by i need the graph only the month vs Arpu, by if i insert the chart this create the columns with all values.

How can i do to do the graph in my pivot table only with a specific column?

Thanks

Comment: This question is probably better suited for Super User

Comment: Thinking i have an idea, my idea is: create the first pivot tables, and add all slicers that i need, and the column to create the chart, later copy the pivot table and (the new pivot table will work with the same slicers) then i add all columns, and i create m chart with the first pivot table, but the complete information is in my second pivot table. And if i change the slicers, (the information change in my 2 pivot tables), then it solution works fine

Comment: My tutorial [Making Regular Charts from Pivot Tables](https://peltiertech.com/regular-charts-from-pivot-tables/) might help.